# OnClick Event isn't Fired When OnConfigurationChanged is Triggered

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I've created a custom navigation page to handle back navigation button event.

The click listener is properly attached to the toolbar, but somehow the OnClick event isn't being fired when orientation is changed for some reason. It works just fine before changing the orientation. Could anyone help me figure this out? I've been trying for weeks.

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Util;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat;

using RichyInspect.Renderers;
using RichyInspect.Droid.Renderers;
using Android.Content.Res;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(VNavigationPage), typeof(VNavigationPage_Android))]
namespace RichyInspect.Droid.Renderers
{
    // Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87795/onoptionsitemselected-not-invoked-using-masterdetails-page-on-android
    public class VNavigationPage_Android : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        public VNavigationPage_Android(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            AutoPackage = false;
        }

        protected override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
        {
            base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            Element page = Element.RootPage;
            MasterDetailPage masterDetailPage = null;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("page: " + (page == null).ToString());
             masterDetailPage = page as MasterDetailPage;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("masterDetailPage: " + (masterDetailPage == null).ToString());
            if (masterDetailPage == null)
                return;

            var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(masterDetailPage) as MasterDetailPageRenderer;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("renderer: " + (renderer == null).ToString());
            if (renderer == null)
                return;

            var drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)renderer;
            Toolbar toolbar = null;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ChildCount: " + ChildCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var child = GetChildAt(i);
                toolbar = child as Toolbar;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ID:" + toolbar?.Id);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("toolbar: " + (toolbar == null).ToString());

            toolbar.SetNavigationOnClickListener(new MenuClickListener(Element, drawerLayout));
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();

            Element page = Element.RootPage;
            MasterDetailPage masterDetailPage = null;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("page: " + (page == null).ToString());
            masterDetailPage = page as MasterDetailPage;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("masterDetailPage: " + (masterDetailPage == null).ToString());
            if (masterDetailPage == null)
                return;

            var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(masterDetailPage) as MasterDetailPageRenderer;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("renderer: " + (renderer == null).ToString());
            if (renderer == null)
                return;

            var drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)renderer;
            Toolbar toolbar = null;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ChildCount: " + ChildCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var child = GetChildAt(i);
                toolbar = child as Toolbar;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ID:" + toolbar?.Id);
                if (toolbar != null)
                    break;
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("toolbar: " + (toolbar == null).ToString());

            toolbar.SetNavigationOnClickListener(new MenuClickListener(Element, drawerLayout));
        }

        private class MenuClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnClickListener
        {
            readonly NavigationPage navigationPage;
            private DrawerLayout layout;

            public MenuClickListener(NavigationPage navigationPage, DrawerLayout layout)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("page: Listening");
                this.navigationPage = navigationPage;
                this.layout = layout;
            }

            public void OnClick(Android.Views.View v)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("page: Clicked");
                var page = navigationPage.CurrentPage as VContentPage;
                var master = navigationPage.CurrentPage as MasterDetailHomePage;
                if (navigationPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count <= 1)
                {
                    layout.OpenDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
                }

                if (page != null)
                {
                    if (page.CustomBackButtonAction == null)
                    {
                        navigationPage?.PopAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        page.CustomBackButtonAction.Invoke();
                    }
                }
                else if (master != null)
                {
                    master.RetractMaster();
                }
                else
                {
                    navigationPage?.PopAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your click event might not be working is that after onConfigurationChanged is called on configuration change you are not reassigning the values to your objects.

Try something like this:

```
 protected override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       if(newConfig.Orientation==Orientation.Landscape)
           //Code for landscape mode
        else if(newConfig.Orientation==Orientation.Portrait)
           //Code for potrait mode
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is your onConfigChange ever called?

Comment: Yes. It's called normally.